# Oracle UTL_FILE file corruption

Tags: oracle, plsql, utl-file

Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

We have the below procedure that reads blob data ( docx file) and writes to a directory using UTL_FILE. The file is correctly stored in the blob column and we are able to download and open the file.

However when we try to open the file that was written to the directory, the file is corrupted.

Below is the code snippet used to write the file. We are unable to determine whu UTL_FILE is causing the file corruption. Has anyone faced a similar issue writing docx files ?

```
DECLARE
  l_file      UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  l_buffer    RAW(32767);
  l_amount    BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
  l_pos       INTEGER := 1;
  l_blob      BLOB;
  l_blob_len  INTEGER;
BEGIN
  
  SELECT blob_file
  INTO   l_blob
  FROM   tab1
  WHERE  id=1;

  l_blob_len := DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_blob);
  
  l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('DB_DIR','file.docx','wb', 32767);

  
  WHILE l_pos < l_blob_len LOOP
    DBMS_LOB.read(l_blob, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
    UTL_FILE.put_raw(file      => l_file      ,
                                buffer    => l_buffer,
                                autoflush => true);
    l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;
  END LOOP;

  UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);
  
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF UTL_FILE.is_open(l_file) THEN
      UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);
    END IF;
    RAISE;
END;
/
```

Appreciate any help in this regard

Thanks in advance

Comment: You leave the loop and don't write the latest chunk of data: the bytes between ((l_blob_len DIV l_amount) * l_amount) and l_blob_len.

Comment: This code seems to work fine - using it to write a .docx stored as a BLOB to a file is not corrupting it. But as `l_out_file` had to be changed to `l_file` to make it run, it's unclear if this is actually your code or if you've retyped it and avoided some error in the original in the process. What corruption do you see - is the length different, or is it more subtle? And how have you verified that it was stored correctly in the first place?

Comment: @AlexPoole that was a typo during copy paste & i fixed it. When the docx is opened using word, word throws a warning of unreadable content found in docx file and asks to click ok to recover the file, upon which the file opens fine. When I compared a file that did not have this error with a file that had the error (opened them in sublime text ) I see some characters missing at the end of the file ( 00 ) but I can't figure out which characters are missing.

Comment: Thanks @p3consulting for your answer , the dbms_lob.getlength gives me 18442 so not sure how the latest chunk got truncated. Also the while condition is l_pos < blob_len and not  l_pos <= blob_len .

Comment: "The file is correctly stored in the blob column" - but how do you know that, and that the file wasn't corrupted as it was stored, or even before that? Do you have the original file to compare it with? You can [hash the BLOB](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_CRYPTO.html#GUID-0F265319-B269-4CC1-B4FB-2C91EE1CE54E) with MD5, and hash the file written to disk, to confirm the corruption is from your code. If those hashes are the same then the BLOB is already corrupt. If they are different then this code is the problem, though I don't see how at the moment...

Comment: When I downloaded the blob in the table from sql developer / apex UI & open the file, it opens fine without any word warning. When the same blob is written to directory using above code & that file opened, the word docx is corrupted.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. I still can't see anything wrong with your code though. The only way I can get it to behave like this is to open the file in `'w'` mode instead of `'wb'`, which seems to essentially add a new line character to the end, rather than nulls (00). What is the size difference between the same file downloaded from SQL Developer and through UTL_FILE?

Comment: Also have in mind that according to documentation, `amount` parameter stands for: 

 Number of bytes (for BLOBs) or characters (for CLOBs) to read, or
 number that were read (after successfull call of the function).

Comment: Thank you AlexPoole , Bartosz Olchowik and @p3consulting for the responses. The last set of bytes/chars were not getting written to the file which was causing word to throw the corruption warning. Changing the while loop to  l_pos <= l_blob_len seems to have resolved the issue..